# A silly question on range of a quadratic function.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, quadratics

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\space|\space f(x) = x^2 + 3x + 2 \space\forall\space x 
\in\mathbb{R}$

We are asked to find the range of the function $f$

I begin as follows:

Assume $y=x^2 + 3x + 2$ for some $ x\in\mathbb{R}$

Collecting terms to one side,

$x^2 + 3x + 2-y=0$

Now as x is real, the discriminant of the above quadratic expression must be greater than or equal to zero. Hence,

$3^2 - 4(1)(2-y)\geqslant0$

Solving, we get,

$y\geqslant-1/4$

Hence the range of the function $f$ is the set $A=\{x|x\geq-1/4\}$

This answer is correct. The range of the function $f$ is indeed the set $A=\{x|x\geq-1/4\}$.

However, I have a problem with my last step. The final equality only tells me that $y$ is greater than **OR** equal to $-1/4$. It doesn't exactly say that $y$ **WILL** take all values greater than **AND** equal to $-1/4$. Is there a way to prove that $y$ will take all such values?

Any hint or help regarding this will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: The function is continuous and approaches $+ \infty$ as $x\to \pm \infty$.  It follows that, if $f(x)$ takes the value $y$, then it takes all greater values.

Comment: You have shown that $x^2 + 3x + 2-y=0$ has a solution *if and only if* $y \ge -1/4$.

Comment: I think you're misinterpreting the symbol $\ge$. The set $\{y \in \mathbb{R} \mid y \ge -1/4\}$ *includes* the value $-1/4$. Each value may only be greater than *or* equal, but the solution includes both the values that are greater than, *and* the one value that is equal.

Answer (score 9):

I would write this as $y = (x+\frac32)^2-\frac14$, from which it is obvious what the range would be, as the square term takes all nonnegative values.

Comment: That is certainly a better way to do it, but I was experimenting with the other ways there are to approach the problem.

Comment: @RajShukla Your approach works well too, as others noted you have proved for every $y\ge -\frac14$, there is at least one real value of $x$, and not for any other $y$, so the range is established

Answer (score 5):

In your solution, you show that $x$ has a real value if $y\geq -1/4$ using discriminant of a quadratic. Well this works the other way too! If $y\geq -1/4$, then the quadratic has nonnegative discriminant and so you will always find $x$ that give that specific value of $y$.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: That makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Your calculation is correct and complete if you write it like this:
$$
\begin{align}
 &\text{$y$ is in the range of $f$} \\
\iff &x^2 + 3x + 2-y=0 \text{ for some } x \in \Bbb R \\
\iff &\text{the discriminant of $x^2 + 3x + 2-y$ is non-negative} \\
\iff &y \ge -1/4 \, .
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you! This clears my doubt

Answer (score 2):

I think the OP’s doubt is that “f(x)$\geq\frac 14$“ states that any values taken by f(x) are greater than or equal to $\frac 14$, but not that f(x) takes all values greater than or equal to $\frac 14$.

---

Note that $y=f(x)$ is continuous and differentiable on all points in $\mathbb R$.

The minimum value of a quadratic function $$ax^2+bx+c=a\left(x+\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2+\frac{4ac-b^2}{4a^2}$$ occurs at $\displaystyle x=-\frac{b}{2a}$ so there exists some x such that the minimum occurs.

Now, take an interval $\left[-\frac{b}{2a}, q\right]$ where $q\gt-\frac{b}{2a} $ is some real number.
Then, by the Intermediate Value Theorem, the function is guaranteed to take on *all* the values  between $\displaystyle -\frac{b}{2a}$ and $f(q)$. Notice that f(x) is increasing in $\left(-\frac{b}{2a},\infty\right)$ so $\displaystyle f(q)> -\frac{b}{2a}$. You can keep increasing q indefinitely and so we can conclude that f(x) assumes all values greater than and including $-\frac{b}{2a}$.

(**P.S.** a similar exercise can be carried out using $q’< -\frac{b}{2a}$.)

Thus, we have proved that the function is ***guaranteed*** to take on all the values  greater than and including its minimum.

Comment: Thank you! That clears a lot of stuff for me.

Comment: Oh, yes. I’ll fix it.